# Unable to Write in MUI SearchBar

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I am able to display a Material UI search bar but I am unable to type anything into it. How can I fix this?

I have tried using the code snippets given as current answers but they give errors in my existing code.

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react'
import SearchBar from 'material-ui-search-bar';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import PermanentDrawerLeft from '../../components/drawer/drawer';


const userSearchPage = () => (
<div>
    <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
    <MuiThemeProvider>
            <DropDownMenu >
            <MenuItem style={ {fontSize: "20px" } } primaryText="Search By"/>
            <MenuItem value={1} style={ {fontSize: "20px" } } primaryText="First Name" />
            <MenuItem value={1} style={ {fontSize: "20px" } } primaryText="Last Name" />
            </DropDownMenu>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
            <SearchBar
      onChange={() => console.log('onChange')}
      onRequestSearch={() => console.log('onRequestSearch')}
      style={{
        margin: '0 auto',
        maxWidth: 800
      }}
    />
            </div>
    );

export default userSearchPage;
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you are missing the state of your SearchBar component, you need to keep a state for searchBar input value.

```
<SearchBar
value={this.state.value}
onChange={(newValue) => this.setState({ value: newValue })}
onRequestSearch={() => console.log('onRequestSearch')}
  style={{
    margin: '0 auto',
    maxWidth: 800
  }

 />
```

Comment: Please see my updated full code. If I try to replace my code with your snippet, I get multiple errors. For instance, at this.state.value, I get ```The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'.```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `hook` and have the value there and then update it on changes made to the field.

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react'
 ...
 const [text, setText] = useState("");
 ...
 <SearchBar
      onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
      value={text}
      onRequestSearch={() => console.log('onRequestSearch')}
      style={{
        margin: '0 auto',
        maxWidth: 800
      }}
    />
```

Comment: Could you please see my updated qs? Your code snippet gives an error in my code ```useState can only be used in a function```

Comment: Thats because you might be using hooks in class based component. hooks can only be used in functional components. For reference : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html
I have added another code snippet its using react useState hook for managing state of the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SearchBar from "material-ui-search-bar";
import MuiThemeProvider from "material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider";
import DropDownMenu from "material-ui/DropDownMenu";
import MenuItem from "material-ui/MenuItem";
import PermanentDrawerLeft from "../../components/drawer/drawer";

const userSearchPage = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <PermanentDrawerLeft />
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <DropDownMenu>
          <MenuItem style={{ fontSize: "20px" }} primaryText="Search By" />
          <MenuItem
            value={1}
            style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}
            primaryText="First Name"
          />
          <MenuItem
            value={1}
            style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}
            primaryText="Last Name"
          />
        </DropDownMenu>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
      <SearchBar
        value={text}
        onChange={value => {
          setText(value);
          console.log("onChange");
        }}
        onRequestSearch={() => console.log("onRequestSearch")}
        style={{
          margin: "0 auto",
          maxWidth: 800
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default userSearchPage;
```